# Is there a way to cancel a pending bot.wait_for?

Tags: discord.py

I have the following code:

```
self.current_task = self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=10 * 60)
response = await self.current_task
```

However I want the bot.wait_for to cancel if a condition becomes true in another function within the same class. I've tried doing self.current_task.close(), however it still waits for a response/timeout before returning a nonetype.

Comment: What exactly is the other function that is becoming true?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable which evaluates if the condition is met, in the check func simply check if it's met and raise an error and catch it in a try/except block

```py
def check(m):
    if self.is_condition_met: # Change the variable accordingly
         raise # Whatever error you want
    return # normal check
```

An example would be

```py
class SomeCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.is_condition_met = False

    @commands.command()
    async def met(self, ctx):
        self.is_condition_met = True

    @commands.command()
    async def foo(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Please send a message")
 
        def check(m):
            if self.is_condition_met:
                raise RuntimeError("condition is met")
            return ctx.author == m.author

        try:
            message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=20.0)
        except RuntimeError:
            await ctx.send("Condition was met")
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("Time is over")
```

If you invoke the `foo` command first, and then the `met` command the wait should be cancelled as soon as someone sends a message

Comment: would the extra check on each message effect performance?